# Cancel form load

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have the following code :

This call the second form

```
private void updateToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Update fm = new Update();
            fm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

This is the constructor

```
    public Update()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This is the load

```
    private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ver = checkver();
        if (ver == "update")
        {
            if (RemoteFileExists(dlUrl) == true)
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(dlUrl), "");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. Please try later.");
        }
        else if (ver == "newest")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are currently using the newest version.");
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

My problem is, that when the function result is 2 or 3 the form show up for millisecond and then close (flashing). I want the form to not flash. Is it possible?

I tried to use **this.Hide()**, **this.Visible = False** but nothing helped.

EDIT: I put the original code
EDIT2: Put more code

Comment: lol what happen? Why I can't write "Hello guys"? :)

Comment: What about putting the code in the form constructor, which will be called before the form_load event happens (depends what happens in funct() theough... if it relies on accessing components that are not yet initialized, then this won't work).

Comment: You should call funct() only once, so that the value you are switching with is guaranteed to be the same, unless you specifically want the possibility that it can change.

Comment: Unless funct() relies on immutable state.

Comment: @Loclip `Why I can't write "Hello guys"?` -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/147640

Comment: `Update_Load` gets called when? Was that a typo for `Form_Load`?

Comment: Problem solved thanks to astro boy

Comment: Can you move `checkver` outside of the class so it can be checked before displaying the form? It sounds like that logic doesn't belong inside the form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hide the form before loading and then set it back to visible in your `if else` conditions. e.g:

```
            MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
            myForm.Opacity = 0;
            myForm.Show();
```

And then:

```
if (ver == "update")
        {
            if (RemoteFileExists(dlUrl) == true)
            {
               myForm.Opacity = 100;
               ...

            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. Please try later.");
        }
        else if (ver == "newest")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are currently using the newest version.");
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: @Loclip: While this solution works, you really shouldn't be calling `checkver` inside of the form. It is logic that belongs in a separate class that should be checked before deciding whether or not to display the form. Setting a form's opacity to 0 is an ugly workaround.

Comment: but it's ok... the hide doing the same

Comment: @Loclip: Well, there's more than one way to skin a cat, but if you're looking for less maintenance headache in the future and more *proper* OOP design principles, then you'd move it out of the form. Your choice of course ;)

Comment: You wouldn't drive to the gas station, then check if you need gas. Check first, then go if you need gas. Just sayin' :)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do so :

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   switch(funct())
   {
      case 2:
         this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
          break;
      case 3:
         this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
           break; 
     default:
           MessageBox.Show("Something");
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do whatever check you're performing before you choose to open the form in the first place.

So something like:

```
if(funct() == "1")
{
    var form = new Form();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `Update_Load` is your `FormLoad` Handler? That is called **after** your form has been displayed. If you don't want to display it, that's too late. Change your `updateToolStripMenuItem_Click` to this:

```
String ver = checkver();
if (ver == "update")
{
    if (RemoteFileExists(dlUrl))
    {
        Update fm = new Update();
        fm.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. Please try later.");
}
else if (ver == "newest")
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are currently using the newest version.");
}
```

And change your `Update_Load` to:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(dlUrl), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe hide it first, then only show it if funct() == "1":

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();

    if (funct() == "1")
        MessageBox.Show("Something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   switch(funct())
   {
      case 2:
         this.Close();
          break;
      case 3:
          this.Close();
           break; 
     default:
           MessageBox.Show("Something");
   }   
}
```