# VB.NET: Load form and hide it

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a form in my project. This form is only there to signalize to other application (for example external ActiveX-exes) that my application is still alive.

I have declared it like this in the main form:

```
Private m_fVirtualContainer As frmVirtualContainer
```

Now when I instantiate it, I say:

```
    m_fVirtualContainer = New frmVirtualContainer
```

However, this does not trigger the form's "Load" event.

I have to add
        m_fVirtualContainer.Show()

... to trigger the Load event.

In the form I have the following sub:

```
Private Sub frmVirtualContainer_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.Visible = False

End Sub
```

But I think and hope that this is an overkill.
I only want to load the form, not show it.

Can somebody please tell me how to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just put the code you need in the constructor for the form? I don't think you can cancel the actual showing of the form from the load. Load() is only called on Form.Show() afaik.

Comment: Which event do you mean?

Comment: Actually, I guess you can just hack it.. see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148671/cancel-form-load

Comment: once you do `New frmVirt` the form is instanced - it exists, do the ActiveX things not recognize it?  or do they need an actual form onscreen?

Comment: Well... The form's load event was not called, so I guess it didn't exist.

Comment: As @Plutonix said when you use the constructor, the form is instanced, I confirm that it exist and can be managed from others...

Comment: The form exists at the end of `Sub New` which is called the constructor, not form Load.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new module to project, this will act as the startup object for the project.

```
Sub Main()
' Instantiate a new instance of Form1.
Dim f1 as New Form1()
' Display a messagebox. This shows the application is running, 
' yet there is nothing shown to the user. This is the point at 
' which you customize your form.
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The application is running now, but no forms have been shown.")
' Customize the form.
f1.Text = "Running Form"
' Show the instance of the form modally.
f1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to use "Sub Main" any longer, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It requires to switch Windows Form Application (most likely used in this scenario) to Console Application. That may be a big deal and even not possible (imagine MDI scenarios, apps with large infrastructure,...)