# How to check internet connection before form loads?

Tags: c#

I have a method that requires internet connection to function, How can I check for internet connection before my form loads? I would like to display an error message box if there is no connection and NOT load to form.

Here's my attempt:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool checkConnection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (checkConnection = false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error no con.");
        }
```

Comment: Look into [Control.HandleCreated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: Do it in constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)

Comment: How does that help @VikasGupta?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel form load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148671/cancel-form-load)

Comment: @Liam, that code will get executed before form load or You can write the same in Program.cs file of your project

Comment: Right, so it doesn't help then @VikasGupta

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code

```
if (checkConnection = false)
{
     MessageBox.Show("error no con.");
}
```

Notice

```
if (checkConnection = false)
```

it's `=` Not `==`

so you should change it and make

```
if (!checkConnection)
```

And FYI `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();`

is not an efficient way of checking for internet connection.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net) for checking internet connectivity